# Hazelcasl Rest API Binary Objects

Tags: java, rest, hazelcast

I am using Rest API client for Hazelcast. The objects stored in MAP are in BINARY format.

How can I view those objects from Rest client?

Comment: What do you mean by binary? What's your serialization format?

Answer (score 1):

I use [`AsyncHTTPClient`](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) library as a rest client.
I assume that you use standard Java serialization and class `Person` implements serializable.

Store object in Hazelcast

```
public class MyHazelcastClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HazelcastInstance hzClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
        Person person = new Person("Vik");
        final IMap<Object, Object> hzClientMap = hzClient.getMap("default");
        hzClientMap.set("key1", person);
        hzClient.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Reading object from Hazelcast using [REST api](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/restclient.html)

```
    public class RestClient {
        public static void main(String[] args)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
            Response r = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet("http://127.0.0.1:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/default/key1")
                    .execute().get();
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseBodyAsBytes()));
            final Person o = (Person) objectInputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps!

Cheers,

Vik

Comment: Is it possible to send a rest request via browser and get let's say a json serialized version of any custom object?